# Как получить доступ к объекту для которого выполняется блок with?

Tags: delphi

Предположим, что где-то в программе у меня есть следующая конструкция:

```
with createAnimal(selectedAnimal) do
begin
    ...
    if(результат_createAnimal(selectedAnimal) <> TDog) then
        ...
end;
```

`createAnimal` - функция, которое создает объект типа `TAnimal` в зависимости от того, что я выбрал... Вопрос заключается в следующем: как узнать результат выполнения `createAnimal` внутри этого "`with createAnimal() do`"?

Comment: Одному мне эта конструкция кажется странной?  
Если вы пытаетесь таким образом сделать полиморф, то вам подобные проверки надо делать в теле конструктора.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, нет, не одному)

---
@delphalex, мне ваш вопрос понятен не до конца...

Comment: Что тут странного? Так зачастую создаются объекты, которые используются прямо на месте и далее не нужны.

Например. Есть у нас функция `Query(SqlCmd: string):TDataset;`, выполняющая sql-запрос и возвращающая набор данных. Тогда мы можем провернуть нижеописанную вещь, не выделяя под датасет отдельной переменной (т.е. scope максимально локализован):

    with Query('select ....') do
    begin
      ...
      //выполняем какие-то операции над полученным набором данных   
      ...
      Free; // Все, набор данных нам не нужен.
    end;

Answer (score 2):

Ну посмотрим...

```
with createAnimal(selectedAnimal) do
```

Тут вы пытаетесь вызвать конструктор класса, и указать, что дальше будет происходить работа с результатом функции. Вот только вы никакой переменной результат функции не присваиваете.

В общем делайте по старинке:

```
var
  NewAnimal: TAnimal;
  ...
Begin
  ...
  NewAnimal:= createAnimal(selectedAnimal);
  if {а тут уже делайте проверки свойств объекта} then 
   begin
   ...
   end;
  ...
end;
```

**UPD:**

В вашем случае правильно будет так:

```
with createAnimal(selectedAnimal) do
begin
    ...
    if(ClassType <> TDog) then
        ...
    free;
end;
```

Comment: > объект типа TAnimal не создается

Не путайте. Объект создается, но вот ссылка на него не присваивается переменной.

Comment: Объект точно создается (иначе как можно было бы вызвать его методы?). Вот только ссылка на него явно не доступна.

Comment: Пардон. исправил.   

Узнал что-то новое - день прошел не зря.

Comment: Как в этом мире все меняется. Ещё вчера писал, что делать нельзя, а сегодня уже вижу обновления, которые с моего комментария взяты.

Comment: Что плохого в том, что я запустил IDE, создал проект и разобрался в этой теме? В этом мире все меняется. Что плохого в том, что я, разобравшись в данном вопросе, и признав свою неправоту в изначальном ответе, исправил свой ответ?  И вообще, я обновил свой ответ через 15 секунд, после того, как @xEdelweiss написал свой ответ, а следовательно я не знал о его ответе, и вы еще не написали свой комментарий.

Answer (score 2):

Что если попробовать через [ClassName()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.TObject.ClassName)? Т.е., что-то вроде:

```
if (ClassName == "TDog") then ...
```

Или вовсе добавить к TAnimal метод `Me()`, который вернет `self` или `self.ClassName`:

```
if (Me is TDog) then ...
```

Дополнение от [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) по использованию [ClassType()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.TObject.ClassType):

```
if (ClassType is TDog) then ...
```

Comment: может даже лучше ClassType() - он ссылку на тип возвратит. Тогда можно писать `if not (ClassType() is TDog) then`

Но мне кажется, что правильно будет определить свой метод, который и будет определять "свой-чужой". тогда не нужно сравнивать.

Comment: Не подумал в этом направлении. Дополнил ответ, а автор пусть выбирает.

Answer (score 2):

Правильным ответом здесь было бы вообще не использовать оператор **with**. Он весьма неудачен в Delphi: засоряет пространство имен свойствами объекта, причем без возможности явного обозначения операдна **with**.
Я допускаю использование оператора напр. в таком ключе:

```
begin
// ...
  with TMyForm.Create(nil) do
  try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free
  end;
// ...
end;
```

Главное, чтобы внутри **with** было как можно меньше кода, пара строчек - это нормально, а вот экран или половина, это уже тяжело читать.

P.S. Проверять тип лучше с помощью оператора **is**, он учитывает наследование, в отличии от сравнения **ClassName** или **ClassType** на равенство.

P.P.S. Если получается ветвящийся код, с частыми проверками типа объекта, то это говорит о неправильной декомпозии/архитектуре.

Answer (score -2):

Используйте `Self` - указатель на этот объект.

Comment: неверно. Self - это указатель на объект класса, в методе, которого выполняется код.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, может действительно ошибся... Я думал что with меняет Self. Надо опробовать.

Comment: Пробуйте:

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      with TLabel.Create(Self) do
      begin
        Parent:=Self;
        Caption:='Label';
        Self.Caption:='Form';
      end;
    end;